# Better way of passing properties of base class to derived class?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Consider having the following code:

> ```
> public class TheBase
> {
>    public int One { get; set; }
>    public int Two { get; set; }
>    public int Three { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class Derived : TheBase
> {
>    public Derived(TheBase theBase)
>    {
>       One = theBase.One;
>       Two = theBase.Two;
>       Three = theBase.Three;
>    }
>
>    public int Four { get; set; }
>    public int Five { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Is there an easier way to pass the properties "One", "Two" and "Three" from the base class, to the derived class? Is there some kind of a neat hack available, or this is the best optimal solution for such a problem?

Comment: Why are you passing an instance of `TheBase` as constructor parameter to a `Derived` instance?

Comment: if the properties on the base class are public/protected, you should have access directly to them, no? what's the purpose of copying the values of the base class to the derived class? what are you trying to do?

Comment: You may use some reflection and copy all properties from base-class. But this just hides the complexity, in fact it´s similar tto your approach. What problems do you encounter with it? Seems pretty okay to me.

Comment: @rmszc81 I need to return another object, whose properties include the base object's properties, as well as a few additional ones, such as "Four" and "Five". They are defined later down the road.

Comment: @HimBromBeere No problems encountered! Just a general question if there's a better approach to it than this!

Comment: @SpiritBob If that is the case you might not even need inheritance but need an interface instead.

Comment: @Aphelion interface would end up causing the same overhead I think. I'd rather have a base class, which makes sense in my case. I'm extending an already defined object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the proper implementation:

```
public class TheBase
{
    public int One { get; set; }
    public int Two { get; set; }
    public int Three { get; set; }
    public TheBase(int one, int two, int three)
    {
        One = one;
        Two = two;
        Three = three;
    }
    public TheBase(TheBase theBase)
    {
        One = theBase.One;
        Two = theBase.Two;
        Three = theBase.Three;
    }
}
public class Derived : TheBase
{
    public int Four { get; set; }
    public int Five { get; set; }
    public Derived(TheBase theBase, int four, int five) : base(theBase)
    {
        Four = four;
        Five = five;
    }
    public Derived(int one, int two, int three, int four, int five) : base(one, two, three)
    {
        Four = four;
        Five = five;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still, what problem is he trying to solve? Why is the Object Initializer Syntax not sufficient?

Comment: @MarcoSalemo thank you, it wasn't necessary to include Five and Four in the constructors, I'm aware I can do it like this. I feel like either approach is fine. Just making sure that there isn't something far better than the implementations shown here.

Answer (score -1):

Just work with the derived class as if the base class properties were created in the derived class.
Tip: use the proper modifiers in order to keep things encapsulated. Something like:

```
public abstract class TheBase
{
   protected int baseOne { get; set; }
   protected int baseTwo { get; set; }
   protected int baseThree { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : TheBase
{
   public int Four { get; set; }
   public int Five { get; set; }

   public void SomeCode()
   {
       baseOne = 1;
       baseTwo = 2;
       baseThree = 3;
       Four = 4;
       Five = 5;
   }
}
```

(I use this "base" prefix in order to know which properties comes from the base class, but of course it is not necessary).

Comment: That's exactly what my code shows? I'm working with the derived class by creating the properties of the base class in it.

Comment: Yeah, but you are passing the base class to the constructor of the derived class. That is not necessary. You can access the base class properties directly.

Comment: tell me how you can access the base class properties when they don't even exist? The code and question I'm posing is about constructors, and how to construct a derived class from the base class with the most efficiency.

Comment: Once you inherit "Derived" class from "TheBase" class, you automatically have access to "TheBase" properties and methods declared using either protected or public modifiers.

Comment: It seems you've missed my point once again. In order to pass the properties held by an object from the base class, you'll need to either pass such an object to the derived object's constructor, or do what Marco Salemo is doing. Your code doesn't demonstrate anything in regards to the topic at hand. It just shows how to initialize properties by the use of some method (not even a constructor).

Comment: Hum... maybe your question was not clear enough then? It has generated many doubts, as you can see reading previous comments from other users.